# Rails4.2 'flat-ui-pro.less' wasn't found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[参考サイト](http://joanswork.com/add-flat-ui-pro-to-rails/)を参考にFlat-ui-proの適応をしているのですがうまくいきません
**Step 3**までこれたのですが下記のエラーが出てしまいます。
どうしたら良いでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

やや古い情報ですが同様のエラーが  'lib/designmodo/flatuipro/rails.rb' を 'lib/designmodo-flatuipro-rails.rb' に変更することで解決したとの報告が見つかりました。

いかがでしょうか？

https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails/issues/3